# asp.net Loop through Datalist and get values of non-control items on button click

Tags: asp.net

Loop through [Datalist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) and get values of non-control items( cell values?) on button click

**for (int i = 0; i < datalist1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            datalist1.Items[i].
        }**

Name:       '<%#Eval("ElementName")%>' 

wanna access elementname... by looping through datalist on button click event... button is not on datalist

Comment: you have to be more specific. What do you mean by non-control items?

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your correctly I dont think this is possible, why not just replace it with say a literal, eg

```
<asp:Literal ID="litFoo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ElementName") %>' />
```

Then

```
foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
    {
        if (dli.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || dli.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Literal foo = dli.FindControl("litFoo") as Literal;

            //Or, get the text
            string text = ((Literal)dli.FindControl("litFoo")).Text;

        }
    }
```